# Yet another "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" from Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, web-component

Despite a lot of similar questions on SO, could not find an answer that would work for me. In essence, here is my very simplified Vue single-file component:

*Listing.vue:*

```
<template>
  <section class="main">
    Component
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'todoapp-listing',
    …
  }
</script>
```

Now I need to render it in a Web Component:

*wrapper.js:*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Listing from './src/Listing.vue';

class Wrapper extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const appWrapper = document.createElement("div");
    appWrapper.classList.add('todoapp');

    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).appendChild(appWrapper);

    new Vue({
      render: h => h(Listing),
    }).$mount(appWrapper);
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-wrapper", Wrapper);
```

When this Web Component is being added to a page, I get the following in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Listing> at src/Listing.vue
       <Root>
```

Have tried adding `vue$` alias to webpack config. Didn't help. Babels is running with `@babel/preset-env`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you building this? With your own webpack config? Have you considered using [`vue cli`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) ?  With that being said you can try to change this line: `render: h => h(Listing)` to this: `render(h){ return h(Listing)},`

Comment: Hey @MattOestreich thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it and many other possible ways of rendering (incl. replacing `render` with `template`) but nothing works for me. When it comes to building: it's a React project where I need to include a Vue component from Vue project.

Comment: a react project that needs to include a vue component? What a mess... I'm guessing this is part of a code migration or something?

Comment: @splitter - you can use Vue cli to specifically build .Vue files to web components. `vue build --target wc my-componemt.vue` - works like a charm. From there you can include the built files in your react project. You can keep Vue cli separate - it doesn't have to be a project dependency, etc

Comment: @spliter, can you share your Webpack/rollup config?